# Windows Explorer doesn't work after try to create GodMode

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer, godmode

I saw this: [God Mode for Windows 7](http://brandonlive.com/2010/01/04/the-so-called-god-mode/) and tried if this works on Windows Vista too. I created an Folder on my Desktop and named it `GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}`.
After this, I not even opened it, my Windows Explorer crashed and showed this dialog:
[image: Windows Explorer Error]
I tried to restart(Programm neu starten) Windows Explorer and when it restarted it shows the same dialog again.
So I can't delete the folder because Windows Explorer isn't working and to get it fixed I need to delete the file.

When I try to start other processes via taskmanager, it simply does not work.

When I start in save mode the Windows Explorer appears and starts to flicker, so I'm unable to do anything.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Don't put it on your desktop, make it on the C drive and drag a shortcut to it onto your desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find a way to delete that folder. Here are some methods.

### Find a Command Prompt

**From Safe Mode**

1. Boot into **Safe mode with Command Prompt** and enter the following commands.
2. `cd C:\Users\[your user name]\Desktop`
3. `rmdir GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}`

**From the  System Recovery Options Menu**

1. Press **F8** before the Windows logo appears
2. On the **Advanced Boot Options screen**, select **Repair your computer**
3. Once you get to the **System Recovery Options menu** select **Command Prompt** and enter the following commands.
4. `cd C:\Users\[your user name]\Desktop`
5. `rmdir GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}`

### Find a Way to Edit Your File System

**Live CD**

Find a [Live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) and use it to access your file system. Once you're able to do that, delete the God Mode directory.

Comment: When I boot in save-mode the Windows-Explorer is flickering and I can´t do anything

Comment: @Paedow If you can get to the **[System Recovery Options menu](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-are-the-system-recovery-options-in-Windows-Vista)** you can use the Command Prompt there.

Answer (score 0):

I reconstructed your error and tried to fix it. Here is the solution:

Start Safe mode without drivers and wait until your explorer.exe is coming up. Start the taskmanager and stop explorer.exe. Start explorer.exe in taskmanager and wait about a minute. the windows explorer will stop flickering and you are able to work.

**Attention:**
As you click or rightclick on the `Godmode` folder your explorer will start again flickering.
Now you can start up `cmd` and 
execute the commands `cd C:\Users\Paedow\Desktop` and `rd GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}`.
Then restart your computer and hope that it worked.